# replace prefixes

Tags: apex, code, number, phone, prefix

Im not sure if I doing this right, I got phone numbers in a form like

Phone = '+421\+42199940054'

Phone = '+421\+421%'
. . .
wrong thing are prefixes, wanted only second '+421'

My code

```
List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Phone FROM Lead WHERE Phone = '\\+421\\+421%'] ;
 for (Lead lead : leads) {
 if (lead.Phone.startsWith('\\+421\\+421')) {
 lead.Phone = lead.Phone.replaceFirst('+\\421\\+421','\\+421');
}

    update leads;
```

Probably I just mixed the meta characters in my code.
Can anyone tell me what I did wrong ?

Comment: Seems like you should fix the UI, not the back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working if i understand the problem right:

```
List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Phone FROM Lead WHERE Phone LIKE '+421%421%'] ;
for (Lead lead : leads) {
if (lead.Phone.startsWith('+421\\+421')) {

  lead.Phone = lead.Phone.removeStart('+421\\');

}
}
 update leads;
```

Depending on the context where this logic is being used (trigger/batch) etc. - the code could probably be further optimized like for e.g. using the query directly in the for loop etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just used substring(5), should have thought about it before.